# Getting the results of a variable length prepared statement in MySQLi

Tags: php, mysqli

I writing an accounting website which has quite a few MySQL statements in it. To prevent SQL injection I use prepared statements for any data which is put in by the user.

In order to prevent having to write the steps of preparing and binding statements I have the following function:

```
function executeSql($mysqli,$query_string,$params=null,$paramtypes=null){
    $nr_params=strlen($paramtypes);
    $query_type = substr($query_string,0,3);
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query_string);
    $queryParams[] = $paramtypes;
    $counter=1;
    if($nr_params>1){
        while($counter<=$nr_params){
             $queryParams[$counter]=&$params[$counter-1];
             $counter++;
        }
    } else {
        $queryParams[1]=&$params;
    }
    // Actual binding of the statement. Taking into account a variable numbers of '?' in the query string.
    call_user_func_array(array($stmt,'bind_param'),$queryParams);
    // Execution of the statement
    $stmt->execute();
    // Part where i'd like to have a substitute for:
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    return $result;
    }
```

In the last part I'd like to return the result because then using the result I can treat each row. The problem is that the mysqlnd driver is not installed on the production server so the function $stmt->get_result() cannot be used. I tried to bind the result into variables but then again, every query returns a different number of columns.

Anyone has an idea how to tackle this?

So in summary (in response to the comments):

**How can I retrieve a results object of an executed MySQLi statement while I cannot use $stmt->get_result();**

Kind regards,

EJG

PS I know the code is not flawless, e.g. if strings are used as variables to bind to the statement but that is easily fixed.

UPDATE:
I came across the function $stmt->result_metadata(); Although supposedly the function name suggests only the meta data the php documentation states that:
"If a statement passed to mysqli_prepare() is one that produces a result set, mysqli_stmt_result_metadata() returns the result object"...

Comment: This is why I prefer PDO over mysqli. You can use prepared statements, and still use fetch associative arrays or objects.

Comment: @Barmar they don't happen to be compatible do they?

Comment: That would be too easy, wouldn't it? Sorry, no.

Comment: @EJG89: try to brief your question.

Comment: @Barmar: you can do the same with mysqli. I'm pretty sure there's a code for (quite simple) wrapper functions that enable you to do so on php.net